# Time zone issue when saving data to Hbase using Phoenix Driver

Tags: hadoop, hbase, apache-phoenix, bigdata

I am new to HBase and using Phoenix driver to connect HBase using Squirrel client. Below query describes my table structure and it has composite primary key with "Alert Id ( varchar)" and "Alert StartTime ( Row Timestamp)".

```
CREATE TABLE ALERT_DETAILS (ALERTID VARCHAR,MACHINENAME VARCHAR(100),PLACE VARCHAR(100),ALERTTYPE VARCHAR(32),ALERTSTARTTIME TIMESTAMP NOT NULL CONSTRAINT CTKEY PRIMARY KEY (ALERTID, ALERTSTARTTIME ROW_TIMESTAMP));
```

When I am inserting data using using below query. I am not able to see the time stamp value which I have given in the query. It is changing (5 hours before) to other value.

```
upsert into ALERT_DETAILS values('956dbd63fc586e35bccb0cac18d2cef0','machineone','AUS','CRITICAL ALERT','2016-12-22 11:30:23.0')
```

After executing the query The timestamp value is changing from '2016-12-22 11:30:23.0' to '2016-12-22 06:30:23.0'.

My system  time zone is EST and please help me how to  change configuration of Phoenix and Hbase

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix uses the system time zone.

Use `tzselect` and follow the prompts. It will output an environment variable that you can set in your .bash_profile or set on system startup.

ie. `TZ='America/New_York'; export TZ`